# Android: Service start Activity

Tags: android

The problem is: Service send me a data every 1 hour and i need to start Activity1. If i do nothing, its all the time will create the same Activity1 and in a 5 hours in stack i will have 5 the same Activities...So, how to kill activity before new one will start ?
Thanks !

```
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), someClass.class);
            getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Comment: Wished there should be sticky post in SO many doesnt bother to check meta BTW +1 great comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how to kill activity before new one will start ?

You don't.

First, your users will attack you with hunting knives for popping up an activity in the middle of nowhere. You do not know what they may be in the middle of doing (playing a game, typing a text message, etc.). Only a very few apps, such as VOIP clients and alarm clocks, should be displaying activities except based upon direct user input.

Second, you don't "kill activity" from a service. Rather you put appropriate flags on your `Intent` to bring the existing activity to the front if it exists (e.g., `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT`), rather than create a new one.

Comment: "your users will attack you with hunting knives for popping up" I know that its bad idea...But this is what they want

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to kill an activity when you can just update the old one.
Killing the activity and re-instantiating it will just result in unnecessary overhead.

Just write the code to reset your existing activity's state every time it gets a new Intent.